# EPiServer: DLL trouble - Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: .net, episerver

I'm trying to get an EPiServer project up and running, but I get this error:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the             requested types. The following information may be a subset of the Type/LoaderException information present - inspect with debugger for complete view.
Check assemblies [EPiServer.Legacy4, Version=6.1.379.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7] and/or types [EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.AutoCorrectionPageDefinitionEventArgs,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.AutoCorrectionPropertyEventArgs,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.DataImporter,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.DynamicPropertyValueTransfer,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.PageTransfer,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.PageTypeTransfer,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.PropertyCategoryTransform,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.PropertyLongStringTransform,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.PropertyPageReferenceTransform,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.PropertyStringTransformer,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.PropertyUriTransform,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.PropertyXFormTransformer,
EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.SetUp,
EPiServer.PageTreeLoader,
EPiServer.PageTreeReader,
EPiServer.PageTreeXml,
EPiServer.SpecializedProperties.PropertyStringReadOnly,
EPiServer.SystemControls.ValidationSummary,
EPiServer.WebControls.CategoryTemplateContainer,
EPiServer.WebControls.CategoryTree]. Information from LoaderExceptions property [Method 'get_TransferContext' in type 'EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.NativeFileTransferEPi4' from assembly 'EPiServer.Legacy4, Version=6.1.379.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7' does not have an implementation.,
Method 'OpenWrite' in type 'EPiServer.Enterprise.Transfer.EPi4.NativeFileTransferObject' from assembly 'EPiServer.Legacy4, Version=6.1.379.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7' does not have an implementation.].
```

I have looked into the dll with dotPeek, and all the types are there. The `methods` it can't find isn't there, but I can't find any version of `EPiServer.Legacy4.dll` that has them.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what assembly that is, never seen it actually. :/ Looks like it might be used to upgrade an EPiServer 4 site? Either case, does it work if you **don't** have that assembly in your bin folder?